# Can debug but Can Not inspect or watch variables in a huge PlSql package in Oracle

Tags: debugging, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I've got a "huge" Pl/Sql package (about 1.4 Mb, about 30.000 lines) running in Oracle database 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit over Solaris.

I can debug it step by step (package is marked as debuggin) but my problem is when I try to watch or inspect any variable, PL/Sql developer show me "Not a Variable" with any variable (varchar2, number, etc ) even I cant watch stuff like this:

```
strTipo VARCHAR2(20)  := 'PRUEBA';
```

I can debug and watch/inspect variables in other small packages, but not in the huge one. dbms_output.put_line is going to drive me crazy.

Many nodes? Oracle can't allocate memory for varibles?

Does anybody if there is some configuration parameter in Oracle or what can I do?

Do the huge package smaller its not a solution for me. I can't do it.

Regards and Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't think the issue is with Oracle, but pl/sql Developer IDE.  Sounds dumb, but try rebooting your local machine running pl/sql developer.

Comment: @tbone - WE ARE MICROSOFT OF BORG!  PREPARE TO BE REBOOTED!!  :-)

Comment: It is not a Reboot problem, and I think It is not a pl/sql Developer problem because with TOAD I have the same problem. I think It is a Oracle restriction maybe many nodes, many variables in memory or something like that. But I don't Know how can I check it to discard. Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely try running the debugging code manually through SQL*Plus or SQL Developer -- maybe you are missing an error or informational message, or other clue.

Answer (score 1):

The package body is just too big. Divide it in several packages. There are also some limits of the plsql engine see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm (10g documentation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(variable);